# Is it possible to rebuild Python3.8 installed by "apt install"?

Tags: python3, sqlite

I am facing module missing issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43993890/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-sqlite3

After some survey, the only way to fix it (as far as I know) is "install missing module in Linux, then rebuild Python"

However, my Python3.8 is installed via "apt install". I do not know how to find my Python3.8 installer path, then rebuild it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does `sudo apt install libsqlite3-dev` (without compiling python) not work? Recompiling the default python might lead to disasters, and Ubuntu heavily depends on it.

Comment: Please do not use references from before 2020 when it comes to python3 and try to find newer references. The moment python3 got to be the default things changed and almost all of the old things are not correct anymore. Modules installed through apt or even pips3 should not need recompiling python3.

Comment: You always can recompile system software yourself, but then you are in charge of your OS, venturing in specialist territory. Perhaps it is better to ask about your real problem instead of asking about what you think can be the solution (the famous "XY" question).